# Android - Layout error

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to create a button. I've done something like this before, but now I got an error and I' can't find out what is it. I think i've got the problem in the xml file, but can't find it :S

So there is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/login_button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying to implemet some kind of facebook login. I'm using the easyfacebook sdk. So here is the java code where i trying to implement the login button:

http://pastebin.com/brHmJKs1

The messages i get is the following:

W/webcore(29941): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

E/SkLayout_wtle(29941): layout error:106 width:0 ellipsizedWidth:0

W/InputManagerService(1171): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@405c4e68

Comment: Can you be more specific.
What is Parent view of ImageButton.
Where and when does this error occured.
Can we see code snippet so it is easier to debug.

Comment: I'm sorry. I get these messages, when I click on the button.

Comment: Is the 5th line meant to read "...80dp" instead of "...80sp"?

Comment: I've edited the post, so there is the complete xml file. In the post you can't see, but there is  </LinearLayout> ofc...

Comment: @Jon yeah, i've tried it, but i got the same result

Comment: It must be something in your code not the xml

Comment: I just tried your xml My friend it works fine.
U must be doing something unsual in the code.Can I see the Code ?

Comment: ofc, i thought the problem is in the xml, but i will edit the post nad add the code

Comment: there is the code, i've uploaded it to pastebin

Answer (score 1):

First close your first LinearLayout in last line.Secondly remove RelativeLayout, that is of no use and then try i hope you will get success.

Comment: It's closed i was inattentive when i pasted the code. When i remove RelativeLayout the i can't see the button, so that was my dummy solution

Comment: He has already cleared that he has used </LinearLayout> 
and other thing is there is nothing wrong with XML i tried it.
Something wrong with code itself

Comment: try with Layout_height="wrap_content" and layout_width="wrap_content" of imagebutton.See if it is working then may be problem with height and width.Just try it then we will see.